# MySQL Backing Up SQL Tables and Data via SSH

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, ssh

I need to backup my MySQL tables.   I can login as root via SSH.  All my tables are under Plesk control panel.

```
mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow`
```

This will give me SQL prompt.

Then I would have to do:
    SHOW DATABASES
    USE dbname
    SHOW TABLES

```
SELECT * INFO OUTFILE /tmp/filename.csv  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY  ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM tablename;
```

This is very time consuming process to save each table on each database as csv file.  I still cannot backup the schema files as .sql files.

```
mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` -e "SELECT * from tablename" databasename | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/' > /tmp/databasename_tablename.csv
```

will not work no file generated.  I tried mysqldump but I do not know each username and password for each database.

If some can provide a shell script to dump all database tables and schema will be great.  Much appreciated.

Comment: You're aware of `mysqldump`, right?

Comment: backing up to a csv is NOT a backup. csv is a text-based format, and you will lose all kinds of stuff from the db, especially index/primary key setups. If you're doing backups, then the user doing the backup should have global privileges anyways...

Answer (score -1):

Because u are the backup guy, have a backupGuy user created with sufficient credentials to perform the task for all db's

Use that -u -p to perform the `mysqldump`

Let's say hypothetically that your non-technical boss were forced to sit and watch what you are enduring now to backup stuff. I would bet her first response would be, "for the love of peet would someone please run a

```
CREATE USER 'backupGuy'@'192.168.2.7' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'backupGuy'@'192.168.2.7';
```

End quote

You now have data and schema baked in.

mysqldump supports dumping out stored proc/triggers/functions with the

`--routines` 
`--triggers` 
options

consider your locking issues as with any approach